# How can I bitmap my gallery image in android studio

Tags: java, android

Hi everyone I am trying to bitmap my image but it gives me an empty bitmap every time I select any image from my gallery. Please help

```
public void start(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, Gallery_Intent); 
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uri = data.getData();

    imageView.setImageURI(uri);
    Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
    // Let's read picked image path using content resolver
    String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
    if (bitmap == null) 
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "failed1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Don't try to get a file path with that `query()`. If you don't want to use any third-party libraries, then, instead, use `getContentResolver().openInputStream()` with your `Uri pickedImage`, and pass that `InputStream` to `BitmapFactory`'s `decodeStream()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can get bitmap of image more easier with Picasso or Glide, the example is using Picasso

```
Bitmap bitmap = Picasso.get().load(uri).get();
```